# How to restore data from BP folder in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, namenode, datanode

Configuration : We have 1 HDFS Namenode & 3 data nodes.

Now, namenode got restarted and for some reason cluster ID got changed (Datanodes were still running)

We tried updating Cluster ID from datanode to namenode and vice-versa but no luck. Namenode & datanode were never able to sync data.

As it was critical and there was less data, we formatted HDFS. (before format we copied whole BP folder to some storage).

Now can we restore the data from backed up folder to HDFS?

Answer (score 0):

Without the NameNode `fsimage` it is impossible to restore the data just with backed-up BP folder. Fixing cluster Id would have been far easier task than restoring the data from BP folder.